# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android

У меня есть класс `Utility` и в нём есть функция для чтения контактов с телефона и вывода контактов в лог. `Untility.java:`

```
protected static void readContactFromPhone(){
    String name, birthday;

    Log.i("Days", "1.1");
    ContentResolver cr = mContex.getContentResolver();
    Log.i("Days", "1.2");
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    Log.i("Days", "2");
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        Log.i("Days", "3");
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Log.i("Days", "4");
            name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            birthday = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE));

            Log.i("Days", name + " - " + birthday);
        }
    }
}
```

Основная проблема со строчкой `ContentResolver cr = mContex.getContentResolver();` При таком варианте приложение вылетает с ошибкой `Unable to start activity ComponentInfo` При варианте `ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();` ошибка `Cannot reslove method`

Метод `mContex:`

```
public Utility(Context context){
    mContex = context;
}
```

`Logcat:`

```
1.1
```

Где я ошибся? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибки здесь нет - вернее нет ошибки кодирования, а есть ошибка проектирования. Не рекомендуется хранить `Context` в членах класса, кроме случаев, когда точно известно, что класс живет только вместе с контекстом. У вас скорее всего происходит следующее. При запуске приложения/основной `Activity` вы создаете класс `Utility` и спокойно присваиваете ему заданный `Context`. Далее `Activity` в какой то момент умирает естественной смертью, а ссылка на умерший контекст у вас остается в `Utility` - оттуда и ошибка при попытке использования недействительного контекста.

Я бы на вашем месте в метод `readContactFromPhone()` передавал в параметрах `Context` или `Activity` - тогда все заработает. А приватный член `mContex` - надо уничтожить во избежание ненужных соблазнов.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦Спасибо за ответ. Теперь появилась другая ошибка `Failed to read row 1, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 53 rows, 43 columns.` последний лог `4`. Скорее всего ошибки не связаны, но я буду очень признателен, если Вы  поможете и с этой ошибкой

Comment: Это уже другая ошибка. Список полей не рекомендуется задавать в виде `null` - задайте их в виде `new String[] {"*"}` и проверяйте значения `cursor.getColumnIndex()` - если он возвращает -1, значит поле отсутствует.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ Я добавил проверку: `(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE) != -1)`, но ни один контакт не подошёл, хотя почти во всех контактах указана д/р

Comment: @SergeRUS это уже другой вопрос. Закрываю тему как исчерпанную.